# Can any tell me what I am doing wrong?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position a div to the left of the screen and I am also trying to make it work on any screen resolution and browser.

Here's my code below:-

```css
#Biography {
    background: #ffffff ;
    text-align: center ;
    text-transform: uppercase ;
    color: #fff ;
    padding: 5em 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Conv_Lato-Regular',Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
}

#info {
    left: -10px;  
    float: left;
    top: -80px;
    position: relative;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="Biography">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="tittle">
   
        </div>

        <div id="info">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class=" wow bounceInDown" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
                    <div class="view view-fifth" style="height: 20%">
                        <img src="images/Dan.jpeg"  alt=""  style="height:80%; width:100%">
                        <h4> NAME</h4> 
                        <h5> sean</h5>
                        <h4> OCCUPATION</h4>
                        <h5> Computer Programmer,Software Developer,Student</h5>
      
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
 
        </div>
```

The problem is that the `#info` div is not fully to the left. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: This is positioned on the left of my screen. What are you seeing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the info div is not fully to the left

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 'position:absolute' instead of 'position:relative'  to be located fully to the left in this case.

```
#info {
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;    
color: #000;
```

}